# Webpack and babel together

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

I'm completely new to web development, I've recently installed (via npm) two packages: babel and webpack; reading online their features I've noticed that they both apply a conversion of the code for  the ES6 import/export system to the older one; my question is, if they both apply this "translation" how does it work? Maybe if (for example) babel does the work first then webpack doesn't have to care about it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Weback is a module bundler. As such it has to analyze dependencies among modules, i.e. which modules a given module imports. Webpack now understands both ES6 module syntax and CommonJS module syntax (`require`). Babel is a general code transpiler for JavaScript and can be used to convert ES6 to ES5 syntax. You can decide whether that should include `import` and `export` statements. The effect is that webpack will either work with them as they are or it will work with the CommonJS syntax that Babel produces.

Comment: Ok, so in the "pipeline"  of the building phase, first it operate the babel transpiler and then  webpack bundle the modules; is this true?